# Why does an empty array map to different boolean values in different contexts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean, primitive-types

This looks like a really simple problem, but I've been trying to understand it for a while.

`[]` is the empty array.

`[] == false` gives me `true`.

But `Boolean([])` gives me `true`.

So this code outputs `"Hello, world!"`:

```
if ([]) {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```

But this does not:

```
if ([] == true) {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```

This looks extremely counter-intuitive. Please explain why this happens.

Comment: Don't compare values of different types if you don't expect conversions.

Comment: @MohammadUsman thanks for giving me the link. I didn't know exactly what to search for.